# How to point a domain to another address without access to add CNAME zone

Tags: dns, cname

Ive bought some domains from a hosting service and i want to point them to my other server. I did so usually by adding a DNS zone of type CNAME to list of DNS es which is set in my domain administration panel. but unfortunately I do not have access to add a CNAME, I can only change my name servers. I have even tried to point the name servers to my own domain name server, but this did not work so. for example I have the name servers ns1.online4iran.com and ns2.online4iran.com. but the domain still does not point to my server. is there a way to handle this situation. shall I start a spicific service on my server to handle this thing?
or should I preform specific configurations on my own domain configuration page?

thanks,

Comment: this question would best fit at http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

I did notice that some domain sellers do this, not sure why the monopoly. Sometimes, the changes don't reflect immediately. Wait for sometime & if still they don't reflect then do this. Check in the DNS Settings of your domain control panel if you have an option of 'Child Nameservers'. If yes, then you can run DNS service on your server locally & then make the necessary DNS changes on the server itself. Is your server Linux or Windows? Does it have a control panel installed?